# Swift AVFoundation Camera close open button action error

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I have working barcode scanner codes and it have auto opening camera with viewDidAppear i want to change it with button actions open and close i try but i dont resolve it my codes under below. ( Also i added closeCamera and openCamera actions )Thanks for help.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: DesignableView!
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.setupCaptureSession()
    }

    //MARK: Session Startup
    private func setupCaptureSession(){
        self.captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput

            //Add the input feed to the session and start it
            self.captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
            self.setupPreviewLayer({
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
            self.addMetaDataCaptureOutToSession()
            })
        } catch let setupError as NSError {
            self.showError(setupError.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    private func setupPreviewLayer(completion:() -> ()){

        self.captureLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

        if let capLayer = self.captureLayer {
            capLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            capLayer.frame = self.cameraView.frame
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(capLayer)
            completion()
        }
        else {
            self.showError("An error occured beginning video capture.")
        }
    }

    //MARK: Metadata capture
    func addMetaDataCaptureOutToSession() {
        let metadata = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        self.captureSession.addOutput(metadata)
        metadata.metadataObjectTypes = metadata.availableMetadataObjectTypes
        metadata.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    }

    //MARK: Delegate Methods
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        for metaData in metadataObjects {
            let decodedData:AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = metaData as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
             self.pCodeTextField.text = decodedData.stringValue

            //decodedData.type
        }
    }

    //MARK: Utility Functions
    func showError(error:String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let dismiss:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler:{(alert:UIAlertAction) in
            alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })
        alertController.addAction(dismiss)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

 @IBAction func closeCamera(sender: AnyObject) {


      // HERE I WANT CLOSE CAMERA WHEN CLICKED

    }
    @IBAction func openCamera(sender: AnyObject) {


       // HERE I WANT OPEN CAMERA WHEN CLICKED
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does "open camera" mean? What does "close camera" mean? What does "i dont resolve it my codes under below" mean?

Comment: @matt this codes openning camera auto when view controller loading i dont want it i want : dont open camera to scan barcode auto , when i clicked openCamera button open and closeCamera button close. u can see codes bottom side them

Comment: Add your `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to view and start capturing session when you want to show(open?) camera and remove the layer from superview and stop capturing session when you want to hide(close?)

Comment: @AyanSengupta yeah i want when button clicked action( open / close ) look at codes below there actions

Comment: As I said, in `closeCamera` call `self.captureSession.stopRunning()` and remove your `capLayer` from superlayer by calling `self.captureLayer.removeFromSuperLayer()`. Do the opposite in `openCamera`. You need to hold your `capLayer` variable to some class property (I have used `captureLayer` for property name here), though.

Comment: @AyanSengupta thanks for idea ayan but im new on swift can u add answer thats for me ? i will test them quickly

Comment: @ guys have any idea ??